# Animation not happening - AngularJS, onsen, cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I have been trying to create simple animation effect (fading) on hiding of the div. Refer to below code.

**HTML code**

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">
  <ons-navigator var="navi">
  <ons-page ng-controller="HomeController">
  <div ng-show="splashPresent" class="check-element sample-show-hide"> &nbsp; test</div>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="Click Me!" ng-click="hideMe()" />
  </ons-page>
  </ons-navigator>
</body>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.sample-show-hide {
 padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:white;
}

.sample-show-hide {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

.sample-show-hide.ng-hide {
  opacity:0;
}
```

**JS Code**

```
module.controller("HomeController", function($scope, $timeout){
      $scope.splashPresent = true;  
      $scope.hideMe = function(){
          $scope.splashPresent = false;
      };
});
```

While after clicking the button, the div is gets hidden, but it doesn't have animation effect applied. Same code works well with browsers though.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a few things, and the answer appears to be in your html header, or in the angular module declaration.

First, check to see if you have included a reference to angular-animate in your header.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

Next, make sure you have placed a dependency on ngAnimate in your module declaration.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

The ng-hide, ng-enter, ng-move (in this case ng-hide) should be properly applied to the container, and the animation should proceed correctly.  See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PSRzo3slJPBPsoeBOmpf?p=preview) for a working example of your code

This will also depend on your device.  Android css animation are supported from 4.1+ and iOS from 7+.  See [this table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) for more information.

Comment: The angular-animate library is already added in script section and app is having dependency for ngAnimate. I am using Lollipop 5.0, hence the issue of CSS animation shouldn't occur as well. But no luck.

Comment: Any exceptions being thrown? What does your angular module declaration & config look like?